# Problem with functions accepting inner classes of template classes

Tags: c++, templates

I have a problem with inner classes in class templates. I have a template class (say: `Matrix<T>`), and a subclass (say: `Matrix<T>::Row`). Now I want to to write a function which operates on instances of the subclass (say: `negate(Matrix<T>::Row &)`). I tried to declare the function with `template<class T> negate(typename Matrix<T>::Row &)`, but when I try to use it, the compiler tells me that it cannot find a match.

Here's an abstract example:

```
template<class T>
class A
{
public:
    class B
    {
    };
};

template<class T>
void x(typename A<T>::B &)
{
}

int main()
{
    A<int>::B b;
    x(b); // doesn't work: Error: Could not find a match
          // for x<T>(A<int>::B) needed in main().
    x<int>(b); // works fine
}
```

Why does the compiler does not manage to find `x` in the first case? Is there a way to modify this that it works (without explicitly specifying the type `int`)?

(I also have similar problems where `x` is of the form `template<class T, class S> void x(typename A<T>::B &, const S &);`, whence I would really like not to be forced to explicitly name all types while doing the call.)

I have tried this with g++ 4.4.3, g++ 4.5.2, and Sun Studio 5.9, all give the same result. Thanks a lot in advance for anything helpful!

Comment: +1 for the [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How should the compiler be able to deduce this? Imagine the following setup:

```
struct A { typedef int T; };
struct B { typedef int T; };

template <typename S> void foo(typename S::T);
```

Now when you say `int x; foo(x);`, there's no way to match this unambiguously.

The point is that you are not deducing a template parameter from a given class template, but rather just an arbitrary, free-standing type. The fact that that type was defined inside another class is not relevant for that.

Comment: That makes sense; thanks! I guess I will change my class Matrix<T>::Row to MatrixRow<T>, that would probably be the best solution for my problem.

Answer (score 2):

That is non-deducible context.  That is why the template argument cannot be deduced by the compiler.

Just imagine, you might have specialized `A` as follows:

```
template <>
struct A<SomeType>
{
    typedef std::map <double, double> B;
};
```

Now this specialization has a nested type called `B` which is a typedef of `std::map<double,double>`.

So how would the compiler deduce the type `SomeType`, given that `A<SomeType>::B` is `std::map<double, double>`?

And in fact, there can be many such specializations, as such:

```
template <>
struct A<SomeOtherType>
{
    typedef std::map <double, double> B;
};
```

Even this specialization has `B` as nested type.

Now if I say `A<T>::B` is `std::map<double,double>`, then can you say what `T` is? Is it `SomeType`? or `SomeOtherType`?

Comment: Thank you as well for your answer! I was hoping that since in my code, there was only one way to parse it, the compiler would do that. But I was wrong...

Answer (score 1):

It would need to deduce the type T for the call to template function x, and template argument deduction is only allowed in a specific set of circumstances:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/compbgpl/v9v111/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp9.bg.doc/language_ref/template_argument_deduction.htm

```
A<T>::B
```

does not seem to be one of them :/