# C++ pass inner structure as parameter

Tags: c++, templates, struct, parameter-passing, inner-classes

There is a structure TOut containing inner structure TIn:

```
template <typename T>
struct TOut
{
    struct TIn
    {
            bool b;
    };

    TIn in;
T t;
};
```

How to correctly pass TIn in as a formal parameter of some method?

```
class Test
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    static void test ( const TOut<T>::TIn &i) {} //Error
};


int main()
{
TOut <double> o;
Test::test(o.in);
}
```

The program compiles with the following error:

```
Error   4   error C2998: 'int test' : cannot be a template definition
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178948/problem-with-functions-accepting-inner-classes-of-template-classes

Comment: @TJD `Tin` would be a known ("concrete") type if it where declared beside `Tout`, or inside a non-template class. At the point where the OP is getting an error, `Tin` is not yet known, because `TOut<T>` is not yet instantiated. BTW, the term "concrete" is normally used in the context of inheritance (opposite of "abstract").

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the `typename` keyword:

```
template <typename T>
static void test ( const typename TOut<T>::TIn &i) {}
```

See [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Answer (score 2):

Why cannot you use the simpler

```
template <typename T>
static void test (const T& i)
```

instead?